# JqueryUI tagit - how can I suppress the new entry text field from appearing?

Tags: jquery-ui, tag-it

For the JqueryUI tag-it widget, I'd like to completely prevent the new extra text entry field from appearing. I'm pre-populating with existing tags, and I'd just like to allow people to delete tags but not enter them.

I can make the new field read-only, but the field remains visible in IE and in both IE and Firefox clicking in the area of the widget causes the cursor to focus on that field.

What I'd like to do is get rid of the extra input field altogether.

There doesn't seem to be a tagit property for this associated with the .tagit() method. Is there something else I can do to prevent the extra field from being created?

Thanks,

doug

Comment: pls provide the link of widget , not able to find it on jqueryui site ..

Comment: @XMen: Link to widget: http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tagit').tagit({
//options
}).ready(function() {
    $(this).find('.tagit-new').css('height', '13px').empty();
});
```

Using firebug we can see that the input field created by tagit is in a `li` element with class `tagit-new`.  We need to set the height otherwise the tag container will squash to a slither when the last tag is deleted, and then we can `empty()` this to get rid of the tag input field.

Comment: First, thank you very much. That worked! The visible extra input field in IE is gone, and there is no focusing on an input field (because there is none) in other browsers. Can I ask a followup question? I didn't know about this extra .ready() you could add after the .tagit() method. Is that something special for tagit? Or something in JqueryUI? Or in Jquery? Anyway, I appreciate it. That was extremely helpful!

Comment: With jQuery you can chain functions together one after another.  The `.ready()` function here is exactly the same as in the standard `$(document).ready(function () {` or it's shortened compadré `$(function () {` in that we are simply saying "when this is finished, do the following"

Comment: Very nice. I need to study up more on Jquery. I just do simple things. By the by, is there a way of receiving email notifications from stackoverflow? I always come back and check the page. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @DougLerner in the prefs tab on your profile there's an allow email notifications checkbox in the miscelaneous section, though i haven't really experimented with that much. Ideally people will reference you in the comment with "@username" (as I didn't do when posting my earlier comment) ;) I believe you are also sent notifications on posts that you mark as favourite with the star icon.

Comment: Thanks, Elliott. I'll try. I've never gotten notifications from stackoverflow before - even though you wrote @myname above. We now return control to the original topic.